# Rails Digest::UUID v5 (vs) Postgresql uuid-ossp v5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, uuid

I'm getting different V5 UUIDs when generating with Rails Digest::UUID and Postgresql uuid-ossp.

**Rails:**

```
[58] pry(main)> Digest::UUID.uuid_v5('e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a', 'e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a')
=> "db68e7ad-332a-57a7-9638-a507f76ded93"
```

**Postgresql uuid-ossp:**

```
select uuid_generate_v5('e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a', 'e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a');
           uuid_generate_v5
--------------------------------------
 6c569b95-a6fe-5553-a6f5-cd871ab30178
```

What would be the reason? I thought both should generate the same UUID when the input is the same, but it is different!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that a patch is proposed so that working string-representation of namespaces can be enabled explicitly

> - The new behavior will be enabled by setting the   `config.active_support.use_rfc4122_namespaced_uuids` option   to
>   `true`.

but, the patch is very recent and it could be still under test. People can be afraid it breaks things. Check

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37681
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37682/files

Meanwhile, a workaround is to pack the namespace string

```
ns=n.scan(/(\h{8})-(\h{4})-(\h{4})-(\h{4})-(\h{4})(\h{8})/).flatten.map { |s| s.to_i(16) }.pack("NnnnnN")
```

In your example

```
irb(main):037:0> n='e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a'
=> "e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a"
irb(main):038:0>  ns=n.scan(/(\h{8})-(\h{4})-(\h{4})-(\h{4})-(\h{4})(\h{8})/).flatten.map { |s| s.to_i(16) }.pack("NnnnnN")
=> "\xE9\v\xF6\xAB\xF6\x98O\xAA\x9D\x0F\x81\t\x17\xDE\xA5:"
irb(main):039:0> puts Digest::UUID.uuid_v5(ns, 'e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a')
6c569b95-a6fe-5553-a6f5-cd871ab30178
```

Comment: Ran into this as well, thanks for the packing code. It would have been great if it raised an error when the uuid was in the wrong format, instead of silently accepting wrong value and computing the wrong output.

Comment: @psmith incredible, it has been more than two years, so I guess they can not patch because of legacy?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an answer to the question about why Rails produces a different result, but if you want to produce v5 UUID in your Ruby code, you could use [`uuidtools`](https://github.com/sporkmonger/uuidtools). It returns the same result as PSQL:

```
  ~ pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'uuidtools'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> UUIDTools::UUID.sha1_create(UUIDTools::UUID.parse('e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a'), 'e90bf6ab-f698-4faa-9d0f-810917dea53a')

=> #<UUID:0x3fe09ea60dd8 UUID:6c569b95-a6fe-5553-a6f5-cd871ab30178>
[3] pry(main)>
```